# Only one row in a multipage ltablex

Tags: longtable, page-breaking, ltablex

I use a long table which goes over multiple pages. In some situations, only one row is on a separate page, but it should be fit on the page before.

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ll}
  \toprule
  1 & 2\\
  \midrule
  \endhead
  \midrule
  Continues next page \dots\\
  \bottomrule
  \endfoot
  \bottomrule
  \endlastfoot
  test & dummy\\
  test & dummy\\
  test & dummy\\
  test & dummy\\
  test & dummy\\
  test & dummy\\
  test & dummy\\
  test & dummy\\
  test & dummy\\
  test & dummy\\
  test & dummy\\
  test & dummy\\
  test & dummy\\
  test & dummy\\
  test & dummy\\
  test & dummy\\
  test & dummy\\
  test & dummy\\
  test & dummy\\
  test & dummy\\
  test & dummy\\
  test & dummy\\
  test & dummy\\
  test & dummy\\
  test & dummy\\
  test & dummy\\
  test & dummy\\
  test & dummy\\
  test & dummy\\
  test & dummy\\
  test & dummy\\
  test & dummy\\
  test & dummy\\
  test & dummy\\
  test & dummy\\
  test & dummy\\
  test & dummy\\
  test & dummy\\
  test & dummy\\
  test & dummy\\
  test & dummy\\
  test & dummy\\
  test & dummy\\
  test & dummy\\
  test & dummy\\
  test & dummy\\
  test & dummy\\
  test & dummy\\
  test & dummy\\
  test & dummy\\
  test & dummy\\
  test & dummy\\
  test & dummy\\
  test & dummy\\
  test & dummy\\
  test & dummy\\
  test & dummy\\
  test & dummy\\
  test & dummy\\
  test & dummy\\
  test & dummy\\
  test & dummy\\
  test & dummy\\
  test & dummy\\
  test & dummy\\
  test & dummy\\
  test & dummy\\
  test & dummy\\
  test & dummy\\
  test & dummy\\
  test & dummy\\
  test & dummy\\
  test & dummy\\
  test & dummy\\
  test & dummy\\
  test & dummy\\
  test & dummy\\
  test & dummy\\
  test & dummy\\
  test & dummy\\
  test & dummy\\  
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

I would like for the third page in that example not to be generated, i.e. the last line should it on the second page. How can I do this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

You can grab a little more space with `\enlargethispage`

End the table

```
  test & dummy\\
  test & dummy\\
  test & dummy\\
\noalign{\enlargethispage{3pt}}
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```